# Android Studio: SQlite db ListView items disappear on startActivity

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new to Android Studio and app creation. I followed Johhny Mansons Youtube quide for new apps, and extended the work greatly.

My problem is, logging out of the app removes items from the list view, upon a new login.

When I implemented login functionality, I changed LoginActivity to the main page, following a startActivity to reach MainActivity.java The app is fully functional once you log in. A can submit a picture and text, it is saved to SQLite and display in ListView tab.

However, whenever I log out, or tab back, and login again. The data is wiped. I believe it is because the startActivity executes MainActivity anew, which could be creating a new database and removing the old. But I am not quite sure of the cause and why it happens. Before implmeneting LoginActivity, the app would retain the data fine.

LoginActivity (Login page)

```
mLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.oButton);
    mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            User user = new User(dbHandlerUsers.getUserCount(), String.valueOf(mUsername.getText()), String.valueOf(mPassword.getText()), null);
            if (validUser(user)) {

                CurrentUser g = CurrentUser.getInstance();
                g.setCurrentUser(String.valueOf(mUsername.getText()));

                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return;
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

MainActivity (Function handling questions)

It is the populateList() that should get myListView to display Questions. It might also be worth noting that I am using two databases, one for users and one for questions.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final int EDIT = 0, DELETE = 1;

EditText questionTxt; //include picture too
ImageView questionImageImgView;
List<Question> Questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
List<Question> OtherQuestions = new ArrayList<Question>(); //Preparing for incoming data
ListView myListView;
ListView otherListView;
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://kaist624.projekt.kse624_projekt1"+R.drawable.no_user_logo);
DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
double myLongitude = 0.0d, myLatitude = 0.0d; //Later remove 0.0d
double qLongitude = 0.0d, qLatitude = 0.0d;
int longClickedItemIndex;
ArrayAdapter<Question> questionAdapter;

private float currentValue;
private long lastUpdate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    questionTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    otherListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    questionImageImgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgQuestion);

    //This make our items in listView clickable on an event.
    registerForContextMenu(myListView);
    myListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            longClickedItemIndex = position; //Position tell where the item was clicked

            return false;
        }
    });

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();
    ...


    final Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Find the currently logged in user
            CurrentUser user = CurrentUser.getInstance();
            String currentUser=user.getCurrentUser();

            //Add question
            Question question = new Question(dbHandler.getQuestionsCount(), String.valueOf(questionTxt.getText()), qLongitude, qLatitude, imageUri, currentUser);
            dbHandler.createQuestion(question);
            Questions.add(question);
            questionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(questionTxt.getText()) + " has been added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            clearFields();
        }
    });

    questionTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            addBtn.setEnabled(String.valueOf(questionTxt.getText()).trim().length() > 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });




    //Populate list view with questions
    if (dbHandler.getQuestionsCount() !=0)  //If there are contacts
        Questions.addAll(dbHandler.getAllQuestions()); //Add content

    populateList();

}

...

    dHandler.deleteQuestion(Questions.get(longClickedItemIndex));
            Questions.remove(longClickedItemIndex);
            questionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
    if (resCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (reqCode == 1) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            questionImageImgView.setImageURI(data.getData());

        }
    }
}

private void populateList() {
    questionAdapter = new QuestionListAdapter();
    myListView.setAdapter(questionAdapter);
    //Add method to search for other phone's adapter list
    otherListView.setAdapter(questionAdapter);
}

private class QuestionListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Question> { //THIS CREATES A GROUP OF QUESTION, DISTANCE AND IMAGE - AS ONE OBJECT
    public QuestionListAdapter() {
        super (MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview_item, Questions);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null)
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

        Question currentQuestion = Questions.get(position);

        TextView question = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qQuestion);
        question.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());
        TextView username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qLongitude);
        username.setText(currentQuestion.getUser());
        //TextView longitude = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qLongitude);
        //longitude.setText(currentQuestion.getUser());
        TextView latitude = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qLatitude);
        latitude.setText(Double.toString(currentQuestion.getLatitude()) + " meters");
        ImageView  questionImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.qImageView);
        questionImage.setImageURI(currentQuestion.getImageURI());

        //TextView distance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qDistance);
        //distance.setText(Double.toString(currentQuestion.getDistance()));

        return view;
    }
}
```

Let me know if I should provide more information.

**Class overview**
 - CurrentUser 
 - DatabaseHandler 
 - DatabaseHandlerUser 
 - LoginActivity
 - MainActivity
 - Question
 - RegisterActivity 
 - User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code its hard to find the issue. What i can make it out is:

1. Try to check if you have created your database correctly.
2. If your database is correct then try to debug if you are getting the data from database in your list view object.
3. If you are getting the data then may be you are not setting the data properly in your listview.

Study the [lifecycle of Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) that can help you understand how the view will be behaving under what circumstances.

Let me know if you face any issue in debugging the code.

Comment: I would love if you could help. (1) I know the database is working, as I've changed MainActivity as the first activity, and it works again. (2) The data is displayed in the list view correctly. Only if I go from LoginActivity -> MainActicity, it will wipe/recreate the database I think. I also found the database is wiped of old entries, from before. So it must be overriding the database somehow. Is there any way I could send you the code?

Comment: I fixed this by including

`Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }`

Comment: Is your problem solved or still something is remaining....As you have mentioned in your previous comment about database overriding.... I would advice you to check this method  onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   
   }